# Counting sheeps

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

So i'm trying to use the push method to solve the couting sheeps problem. Basically in this problem i need to count how many "true" there is in a given array. The array itself is

```
[true,  true,  true,  false,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  true,  false, true,  false,
  true,  false, false, true ,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  false, false, true,  true]
```

And i want to understand why the push method, that seem to REMOVE the last index of the array and RETURN it does not work.

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {

  let a = arrayOfSheep;
  let b = 0;
  let answer = 0;
 
  
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      b = a.push();
        if(b === true){
          answer += 1;
}
}
  return answer;
}
```

In my thinking, each time the for loop goes, the length of array a are reduced by one. So in the final loop the array a is [0] and the if makes the answer variable to be equal to 17, but it always return 0.

Comment: `push` does not remove elements from an array. Maybe you want `unshift` or `pop`? But why modify `a` at all? Why not just count the items by looking at them without popping them out of the array? What's the value in emptying this array as you go

Comment: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds an item to the end of the array and returns the new length of the array.

Comment: There is no reason to remove indexes to count

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is overly complex. If I wanted to count how many items in a list match some criteria, I would just look at each item and increment a counter if it matches until I was done with the entire array.

```
function countTrue(arr) {
  // accumulator variable, at the end of each iteration
  // of the loop, `result` will be gauranteed to have the
  // total number of `true` elements seen so far
  let result = 0;
  // iterate over the entire array
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item === true) {
      // this item is true, increment our accumulator
      result++;
    }
  }
  // return our accumulated result, zero or otherwise.
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the boolean values.

```js
const
    array = [true, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very Good answer. Could you please do explain more on `array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`? I have read documentation and reduce is an array function which goes by element by element of array. If you could explain how its counting only true values in this expression will be grateful to you. I am newbie in JS and learning it from your profile, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to push any new value to simply count unique items in an array.

```js
var array = [true,  true,  true,  false,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  true,  false, true,  false,
  true,  false, false, true ,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  false, false, true,  true];

var total = 0;
array.forEach(function (item){
  if(item){
    total++;
  }
});
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely, you meant to use the `.pop()` method which removes an element from the end of the array - changing the array. You also could have used the `.unshift()` method which removes an element from the beginning of the array. Each of these methods destroy the original array.

You can use `Array#filter()` method and `length` property and still leave the original array intact.

```js
const 
      input = [true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true],
      output = input.filter(sheep => sheep).length;
      
console.log( output );
```

**NOTE**

- If you must use a loop, see below.
- If you must use `Array#pop`, not while looping through the same array.

**`for` loop**:

```js
const 
      input = [true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true],
      
      countSheep = a => {
          let count = 0;
          for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              !a[i] || count++;
          }
          return count;
      },
      

      output = countSheep( input );
      
console.log( output );
```

**`for-of` loop**:

```js
const 
      input = [true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true],
      
      countSheep = a => {
          let count = 0;
          for(const element of a) {
              !element || count++;
          }
          return count;
      },
      

      output = countSheep( input );
      
console.log( output );
```

Comment: So, with the pop() method the original array is destroyed and therefore the loop can't recognize the array a anymore?

Comment: Correct, it's not advisable to change the array that you're looping over. If you must use a loop, you do not need to use `Array#pop` to access the current element; you can simply use the index or if you use `for-of` you would be dealing with the element itself.